# How do buttons style optimize in XAML code?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#00000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="25"/>
</Style>
```

...

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}"/>
    </Grid>
```

I wanna optimize my XAML code. I don't wanna assign a style to each button, but I wish every button to have my style.

Is it possible to do something like this? Only working ... :)

```
<Grid x:Name="gToolBar" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}">
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </Grid>
```

I don't use TargetType only, because I have other buttons with different styles.
I think it available, but i don't know how.

Thanks...

Comment: Simply remove `x:Key="ToolBarButton"` and keep the `Style` part in `Application.Resources` and it will apply to all the buttons in the app. Also if you have different buttons with different styles, make a usercontrol for buttons having those specific styles. and then use them, so that they won't get stylized by using the said method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already said everything that is to be done in the comment, but for further clarification:

> I wanna optimize my XAML code. I don't wanna assign a style to each button, but I wish every button to have my style.

Move the `Style` part to `<Application.Resources>` in *App.xaml* file, Like shown below:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Button" >
     <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#00000000"/>
     <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="25"/>
     <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="25"/>
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Note: I've removed the `x:Key` part. Now this will apply to all the button's that is in the application.

> I don't use TargetType only, because I have other buttons with different styles. I think it available, but i don't know how.

For this you would have to make a custom button as a `UserControl`, thus making them completely different from a usual `Button`. Apply styling to them in their own `UserControl.Resources`. Thus *styling* mentioned in `App.Resources` won't affect these custom made *UserControls*

Answer (score 0):

You should use application resources to do that. add this code to there(`app.xaml`):

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Button" >
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#00000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="25"/>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**UPDATE**
Or if you want this style apply just some part of your application such some special 'Grid' or special `Window` ..., just put it inside `Resource` of that element like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" >
      <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#00000000"/>
      <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="25"/>
      <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="25"/>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

   ... inside code, and your buttons which we eant to apply style for them.

</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think he want all button to have this style, only those in that particular container.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default style for buttons within the grid:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#00000000"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="25"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"></Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you create a resource that uses a control type as key within a container, the style will get applied to all controls of the type within the container. If you want to define the  original style somewhere else (for example because you use it in many place) you can base the local style off the global style.